# ASP.NET @Url.Action does not generate link for downloading files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a blog type website (guided by the 3DBuzz video tutorial) with a back-end (for administration purpose) and a front-end. In both back-end and front-end the user should be able to download a file.

The Action for both the front-end and the back-end:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename)
    {
        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"), filename);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
            return HttpNotFound();

        return File(filepath, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath), filename);
    }
```

The front-end view (the @Url.Action is the same in both the front-end and the back-end):

```
@foreach (var file in Model.Post.Files)
{
<a class="list-group-item file-download" href='@Url.Action("Download", "Posts", new { filename = file.FileName } )' id="@file.FileName">
        <span class="name">@file.FileName</span>
</a>
 }
```

**I do not have any routes configured for this action.**
The thing is that in the back-end the url is generated and I can download the files

```
<a class="file-link" href="/admin/Posts/Download?filename=putty.exe">putty.exe</a>
```

But when i want to download from the front-end... no link is generated:

```
<a class="list-group-item file-download" id="putty.exe">
                    <span class="name">putty.exe</span>
</a>
```

If I create a route in the routeConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute("DownloadFile", "downloadFile/{filename}", new { controller = "Posts", action = "Download" }, namespaces);
```

the generated link is:

```
<a class="list-group-item file-download" href="/downloadFile/putty.exe" id="putty.exe">
           <span class="name">putty.exe</span>
</a>
```

but when I click on this link I get a 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run your webapplication in integrated mode, and add the following to your `global.asax`:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

You probably want to exclude the files in the Content folder from your routing by adding the following line to the global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I have made the modification without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually, I had the route for the admin not correctly configured.